# Find sum of $a+b+c+d$

Tags: quadratics

If $x^2-10ax-11b=0$ have roots $c$ and $d$. $x^2 -10cx-11d=0$ have roots $a$ and $b$ then the value of $a+b+c+d$ is..

Here from both equations,
$c+d =10a$ and $a+b = 10c $ 
and $ac =121$. 
But how I can get the sum $a+b+c+d$ from these!

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.askiitians.com/forums/Algebra/22/28823/quadratic-equation.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given 
$$x^2-10ax-11b=0\tag{1}$$
$$x^2-10cx-11d=0\tag{2}$$
We know that $c,d$ are roots of $(1)$ and that $a,b$ are roots of $(2)$ so:
$$\begin{cases}{c^2 - 10ac - 11b = 0\\a^2 - 10ac - 11d = 0}\end{cases}$$
Subtracting then we obtain:

$$a^2 - c^2 = 11 ( d - b )\tag{3}$$
Then
$$a + b = 10c$$ $$ab = - 11d$$
$$c + d = 10a$$ $$cd =  - 11b$$
And we get that 
$$a + b + c + d  = 10 ( a + c )\tag{4}$$
$$b + d = 9 ( a + c ) \tag{5}$$
$$ac=121\tag{6}$$
Using $(3)$ and $(5)$ we get:
$$\frac{( b + d ) ( a - c )}9 = 11 ( d - b )$$
$$\frac{ a - c }{99} = \frac{ d - b }{ b + d }$$
Then
$$a^2 + c^2  - 20 ac - 11 ( b + d ) = 0$$
Using $(6)$ and solving for $a+c$ we have: 
$$( a + c )^2 - 22ac - 11 ( a + c ) 9 = 0\implies a+c=121\tag{7}$$
Finally from $(4)$ and $(7)$ we obtain 
$$\color{orange}{a+b+c+d=1210}$$

Comment: How 10(a+c)= 10ac